# Scala: Future recover in Future traverse

Tags: scala, future

I have a method, which may throw an Exception depends on passed value:

```
 private def transform(in: Int): Future[Boolean] = in match {
    case i if i < 0 => Future.successful(true)
    case i if i > 0 => Future.successful(false)
    case i if i == 0 => throw new IllegalStateException()
 }
```

And second method, which apply above method to each element of List in parallel way.

```
def massTransform(ints: List[Int])(implicit ex: ExecutionContext): 
    Future[List[Boolean]] = {
            Future.traverse(ints){
               i => transform(i).recover {
                                           case e: IllegalStateException => false
                                          }
   }
}
```

I expected, recover will capture the IllegalStateException and return Future(false). But my code fails with IllegalStateException

Comment: Pattern matching with only `case _` and guard is not idiomatic, has no value over `if`/`else if`/`else`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are throwing *outside* of a `Future`. You need to wrap your exception in a `Future`, otherwise what happens is that the method itself throws instead of returning a failed `Future`. You can simplify your method as follows:

```
def transform(in: Int): Future[Boolean] =
  if (in == 0) Future.failed(new IllegalStateException)
  else Future.successful(in < 0)
```

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/KHbHZVgqSFKQttN6QGr3Ag/4).

This looks like a simplification of your actual logic. If by any chance that's not (or not completely) the case, I recommend removing the unnecessary `Future` nesting as follows:

```
def transform(in: Int): Boolean =
  if (in == 0) throw new IllegalStateException else in < 0

def massTransform(
    ints: List[Int]
)(implicit ex: ExecutionContext): Future[List[Boolean]] =
  Future(ints.map { i =>
    try transform(i)
    catch { case e: IllegalStateException => false }
  })
```

Notice how now the `transform` method throws and exception handling is done in the `Future` constructor.

You can play around with this second version [on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/KHbHZVgqSFKQttN6QGr3Ag/6) as well.

Answer (score 2):

`transform` is implemented in incorrectly, should be:

`case i if i == 0 => Future.failed(new IllegalStateException())`

I guess this is a simplified example, because this code does not really parallelise the computation btw, unless `transform` is in reality doing IO or quite expensive computation.

Comment: `Future` doesn't necessarily parallelize, it should be noted.  But worth noting that as written it's not really asynchronous.